# Devise forgot email, heroku logs show email sent but I don't recieve it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise

Heroku logs says email sent but I don't get it. Locally it works, I get the email with MailCatcher.

production.rb

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {:host => 'rails-follow.herokuapp.com'}
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false 
config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
address: "smtp.gmail.com",
port: 587,
domain: ENV["gmail.com"],
authentication: "plain",
enable_starttls_auto: true,
user_name: ENV["rorymunro123@gmail.com"],
password: ENV["PASSWORD"]
}
```

Heroku config:

```
DATABASE_URL:                   postgres://onbifhsiwcwyzn:nm78UwuX1hKby32PZsfXSgEjqi@ec2-54-197-241-95.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432
HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_SILVER_URL: postgres://onbifhsiwcwyzn:nm78UwuX1hKby32PZsfXSgEjqi@ec2-54-197-241-95.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/
LANG:                         en_US.UTF-8
RACK_ENV:                     production
RAILS_ENV:                    production
SECRET_KEY_BASE:              Long number
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the output of `heroku config`?

Comment: I sorted it following this http://rubyonrailshelp.wordpress.com/2014/01/02/setting-up-mailer-using-devise-for-forgot-password/